# Convert http live streaming to rtsp live streaming

Tags: http, rtsp

How to covert http live streaming in to rtsp live streaming in online? I mean to convert without any software.

Comment: what do you mean "without any software"?

Comment: Apparently there are no hardware converters from HTTP to RTSP.